# Can't access Heroku account account

Tags: heroku

Heroku doesn't recognize pswd. I change password and save on keychain. Heroku doesn't recognize new pswd. Attempt to contact Heroku Help Desk. I need to login to account before help desk is avaliable.

Answer (score 0):

They have an email in contact, why this is happening is going to be an account issue only they can resolve for you but no login is required to email them which will be qued in their account support team